# How to split data into trainset and testset randomly?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a large dataset and want to split it into training(50%) and testing set(50%).

Say I have 100 examples stored the input file, each line contains one example. I need to choose 50 lines as training set and 50 lines testing set.

My idea is first generate a random list with length 100 (values range from 1 to 100), then use the first 50 elements as the line number for the 50 training examples. The same with testing set.

This could be achieved easily in Matlab

```
fid=fopen(datafile);
C = textscan(fid, '%s','delimiter', '\n');
plist=randperm(100);
for i=1:50
    trainstring = C{plist(i)};
    fprintf(train_file,trainstring);
end
for i=51:100
    teststring = C{plist(i)};
    fprintf(test_file,teststring);
end
```

But how could I accomplish this function in Python? I'm new to Python, and don't know whether I could read the whole file into an array, and choose certain lines.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This can be done similarly in Python using lists, (note that the whole list is shuffled in place).

```
import random

with open("datafile.txt", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')

random.shuffle(data)

train_data = data[:50]
test_data = data[50:]
```

Comment: nice solution. But what if i don't know about the amount of data in my file that is maybe our data may contain some million of observation and i need to sample the data in 85% and 15% data sets?

Comment: @desmond.carros take a look at `from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split`
So do it this way:
`X_fit, X_eval, y_fit, y_eval= train_test_split(
    train, target, test_size=0.15, random_state=1
)`

Answer (score 37):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy

with open("datafile.txt", "rb") as f:
   data = f.read().split('\n')
   data = numpy.array(data)  #convert array to numpy type array

   x_train ,x_test = train_test_split(data,test_size=0.5)       #test_size=0.5(whole_data)
```

Comment: Hi, train_test_split accepts python array too. You don't need to transform a python array to numpy array.

Comment: For whoever is wondering, the first item in the tuple that `train_test_split` is the remaining percentage. E.g. `x_train ,x_test = train_test_split(list(range(100)),test_size=0.2)` will return respectively 80 items and 20 items.

Answer (score 18):

To answer @desmond.carros question, I modified the best answer as follows,

```
 import random
 file=open("datafile.txt","r")
 data=list()
 for line in file:
    data.append(line.split(#your preferred delimiter))
 file.close()
 random.shuffle(data)
 train_data = data[:int((len(data)+1)*.80)] #Remaining 80% to training set
 test_data = data[int((len(data)+1)*.80):] #Splits 20% data to test set
```

The code splits the entire dataset to 80% train and 20% test data

Answer (score 9):

You could also use numpy. When your data is stored in a numpy.ndarray:

```
import numpy as np
from random import sample
l = 100 #length of data 
f = 50  #number of elements you need
indices = sample(range(l),f)

train_data = data[indices]
test_data = np.delete(data,indices)
```

Answer (score 8):

`sklearn.cross_validation` is deprecated since version 0.18, instead you should use `sklearn.model_selection` as show below

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy

with open("datafile.txt", "rb") as f:
   data = f.read().split('\n')
   data = numpy.array(data)  #convert array to numpy type array

   x_train ,x_test = train_test_split(data,test_size=0.5)       #test_size=0.5(whole_data)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this approach

```
import pandas
import sklearn
csv = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
train, test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(csv, train_size = 0.5)
```

**UPDATE**: `train_test_split` was moved to `model_selection` so the current way (scikit-learn 0.22.2) to do it is this:

```
import pandas
import sklearn
csv = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
train, test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(csv, train_size = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following produces more general k-fold cross-validation splits. Your 50-50 partitioning would be achieved by making `k=2` below, all you would have to to is to pick one of the two partitions produced. Note: I haven't tested the code, but I'm pretty sure it should work.

```
import random, math

def k_fold(myfile, myseed=11109, k=3):
    # Load data
    data = open(myfile).readlines()

    # Shuffle input
    random.seed=myseed
    random.shuffle(data)

    # Compute partition size given input k
    len_part=int(math.ceil(len(data)/float(k)))

    # Create one partition per fold
    train={}
    test={}
    for ii in range(k):
        test[ii]  = data[ii*len_part:ii*len_part+len_part]
        train[ii] = [jj for jj in data if jj not in test[ii]]

    return train, test
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick note for the answer from @subin sahayam

```
 import random
 file=open("datafile.txt","r")
 data=list()
 for line in file:
    data.append(line.split(#your preferred delimiter))
 file.close()
 random.shuffle(data)
 train_data = data[:int((len(data)+1)*.80)] #Remaining 80% to training set
 test_data = data[int(len(data)*.80+1):] #Splits 20% data to test set
```

If your list size is a even number, you should not add the 1 in the code below. Instead, you need to check the size of the list first and then determine if you need to add the 1.

> test_data = data[int(len(data)*.80+1):]