# How to split a dataset, which has two associated files, into training and test datasets by Python?

Tags: python, dataset

For example I have two files, sentences.txt and labels.txt
sentences.txt:

```
This is a sentence
This is not a sentence
Hello world
Hello world too
```

labels.txt:

```
1
1
0
0
```

Each number in labels.txt is associated with the sentence in sentences.txt in the same position. I would like to randomly select 50% for testing and 50% for training, and it seems that I cannot simply random.shuffle(data) like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412439/how-to-split-data-into-trainset-and-testset-randomly). So how could I split the dataset randomly? Thanks.

Comment: What is the size of your data?

Comment: down vote
accepted
If you want to split the data set once in two halves, you can use numpy.random.shuffle, or numpy.random.permutation if you need to keep track of the indices

Comment: The assumption here is that if you are working with a classifier, you're using either sklearn/numpy/pandas.

Comment: data size is about 10k  lines